# Wordpress not displaying themes in the wp-content/themes folder

Tags: themes, installation

I'll do my best to explain this but its weird to say the least.

So the two default themes (twenty ten and twenty eleven) appear under the Appearance>Themes tab in the wp admin.

However, if I add one new theme to wp-content/themes (even if its just an empty folder) all of the themes fail to show up on the Appearance>themes tab, except for the theme currently in use.

Anyone have any ideas?

--This is on a LAMP server (Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: WordPress display only themes, if exist the [minimum files](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) `index.php` and  `style.css` with the [header comment](https://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header) in the head. A empty folder is not helpful.

Comment: I have the same problem and I don't know what to do

Answer (score 2):

If you have multisite install you have to first enable those new themes in network admin, under "Themes"...

Comment: Its not multisite.

Comment: never happend to me... Question: it was there in the past, or they just did not appear from the beggining of install? Also you wrote that themes folder was empty, actually you should see twentyten and twantyeleven there, otherways its wrong folder you are looking in?

Comment: The themes folder has all the items present.  The admin panel just doesn't display any of the themes.

Comment: then maybee write whats the version of wordpress you are using.. And those themes you try to make working, was ok in different wordpress install? You did them yourselves or downloaded them somewhere? Then if its true try to disable all plugins, maybee some of thme causing this?

Comment: I created them myself and they work perfectly fine on my laptop.  Both are running Wordpress 3.4.2.

Comment: weird, then try to disable plugins, and also try to enable wordpress debug mode, this will show you all errors and also notices which occurs when wordpress is looking for themes in themes folder, maybee some bug in theme which is triggered in different server and online enviroment...

Comment: if theme/plugin causes error wordpress can disable it...

Comment: Debug isn't showing errors and there are no custom plugins installed.

Comment: so upload your theme somewhere, will try it in another wordpress instalation...